# Convert Image to Binary Data using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4

I want To Convert Image To Binary Data using JavaScript w return the Binary Data To use it in a class

also I want to Convert the Binary Data To Image

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How convert image into binary format using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32113907/how-convert-image-into-binary-format-using-javascript)

Comment: Do you mean actual binary data, like able to access individual bytes, or a string representation (base64) of the binary data? The former you would use ArrayBuffer / Typed Arrays

Comment: I need this binary format to use it in a class to insert in sql server